# How to resolve "ImportError: No module named magic "

Tags: python, python-3.x, emulation, firmware

I am trying to emulate a firmware using fermadyne and while trying to extract the zip file using "./sources/extractor/extractor.py -b Netgear -sql 127.0.0.1 -np -nk "WNAP320 Firmware Version 2.0.3.zip" images" 
 I get the following error,
"File "./sources/extractor/extractor.py", line 17, in 
import magic
ImportError: No module named magic" 
I tried installing magic for python3 but the problem still persists. Any suggestions?

Comment: This is a duplicate of this
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40048614/import-error-no-module-called-magic-yet-python-magic-is-installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40048614/import-error-no-module-called-magic-yet-python-magic-is-installed)

Comment: i tried tthat solution..i installed magic for python3 as well. Still the problem persists.